# in place edit, search for nested value and then replace another value

Tags: json, jq, inplace-editing

I have an input JSON document with roughly the following form (actual data has additional keys, which should be passed through unmodified; the whitespace is adjusted for human readability, and there's no expectation that it be maintained):

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {"Filter": { "Prefix": "to_me/" },   "Status": "Enabled" }, 
        {"Filter": { "Prefix": "from_me/" }, "Status": "Enabled" }, 
        {"Filter": { "Prefix": "__bg/" },    "Status": "Enabled" }
    ]
}
```

I need to match `.Rules[].Filter.Prefix=="to_me/"` and then change the associated `"Status": "Enabled"` to `"Disabled"`. Since only the first rule above has a prefix of `to_me/`, status of that rule would be changed to `Disabled`, making correct output look like the following:

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {"Filter": { "Prefix": "to_me/" },   "Status": "Disabled" }, 
        {"Filter": { "Prefix": "from_me/" }, "Status": "Enabled" }, 
        {"Filter": { "Prefix": "__bg/" },    "Status": "Enabled" }
    ]
}
```

I've tried several different combinations but can't seem to get it right.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Showing what you tried is generally helpful -- falls under "showing your work", so we know what context an explanation of *why* an answer works needs to include, and what you already know.

Comment: Also, a good [mcve] makes sample data as short as necessary -- if `Expiration` and `ID` aren't impacted by the logic, f/e, better to take it out. Keeping your sample data short makes it easier for folks to visually scan and compare, and means you can include desired output and actual output alongside the actual input without the question getting too long.

Comment: (...I've edited the question in accordance w/ the above).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the idiom `ARRAY |= map(...)` over `ARRAY[] |= ...`, mainly because the former can be used reliably whether or not any of the substitutions evaluate to `empty`:

```
jq '.Rules |= map(if .Filter.Prefix == "to_me/" 
                  then .Status="Disabled" else . end)'
```

To overwrite the input file, you might like to consider `sponge` from [moremutils](https://packages.debian.org/stable/utils/moreutils).

Answer (score 0):

Doing in-place updates can be done with `|=`, and deciding whether to modify content in-place can be done with if/then/else. Thus:

```
jq '.Rules[] |= (if .Filter.Prefix == "to_me/" then .Status="Disabled" else . end)'
```